# Singleton class & multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

Q: Can a singleton instance be broken when two threads from two different app-domains access the class?

I did some research and found below points relevant.

1. A (.NET) Singleton is unique per App-domain - at least, the common Singleton pattern is. I suppose you could implement a per process Singleton, but I haven't thought about how it would really work....
2. There would be 2 instances of your singleton.
3. The input parameters (arguments) to the method are on the stack. Each thread  have a separate stack. When the running thread switches, the stack is replaced.

Expert advice.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a singleton instance be broken when two threads from two different app-domains access the class?

Yes. It is even possible from the same app domain. Consider this simple singleton implementation:

```
private static Singleton instance;
public static Singleton Instance
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new Singleton();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

It is possible that both threads enter the property at the same time. In both cases `instance == null` is true and a new instance is created. One method already returns the created instance, the other resets the `instance` and returns that one a moment later. Singleton broken.

Much more to read on [thread-safe singletons on the blog of Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).